# How do you reset the orientation relative to the camera?

Tags: camera, axis

As you can see, it is now a nightmare trying to place things in the scene. Is there a way to reset x and y so that everything aligns?
[image]

Comment: I'm afraid we can't see that it's a "nightmare". What exactly are you trying to do? - You can view your scene from front, side or top view with the 1, 3 or 7 keys on the numpad if that's what you mean?

Comment: The axis, relative to the camera are diagonal so if I want to move an object further back I can't simply drag it with G + Y but a combination of Y and X axis. I need to re-orient the axis so that Z, X, Y are centered again.

Comment: Did you try changing the _Transformation Orientation_ (a little left to the _Snap_ button) from _Global_ to _Local_? Is that what you need?

Comment: @taiyo Not local, a custom orientation based on the camera. At least that's how I understand the "relative to the camera" part and "I want to move an object further back".

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann aah ok, makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

When you select the camera and click on the dropdown menu for the *Transform Orientation*, you can click on the `+` button to add a new custom orientation. This will automatically be named after the selected object, in this case "Camera" (I already did this in the screenshot below).

[image: custom transform orientation]

If you use the "Camera" orientation and select an object, moving it with <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> will move it closer/farther from the camera, <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> moves up/down and <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> is for left/right movement. tapping the axis key twice switches to moving on global axis instead of custom.

[image: view from camera]

However, if you want to only adjust certain axes and not all to the camera, it might be best to place an empty in the scene which has the rotation you need and use this to create a custom orientation.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked perfectly when selecting the camera although it did not with the empty. Regardless now it works!

Comment: @TORM3NTO I don't know what you did with the empty, but it does work. Of course you cannot simply add it to the scene, you have to give it a suitable rotation so that it fits your needs.

Comment: Yes but it is not using the whole berries, it is only exploding them into bits and pieces. and it is doing it to all three of the berries that I chose as collection rather than emitting from the emitter only.

Comment: By zooming out I can see the empty is emitting something but it is very small and behaves weirdly. Completely different from the tutorial.
https://imgur.com/9tdBosl

Comment: @TORM3NTO I guess you're on the wrong question here... this was about creating a custom orientation to move objects aligned to the camera. This has nothing to do with emitting particles or anything.

Comment: My bad. It was at night after a long day of work. Sorry!